# How to capture incoming parameters with EasyMock.capture?

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I'm testing a class and wanted to monitor calls to a specific method, namely to save the calling parameters for later analysis.

Testing is done with [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/), so it was logical to use [EasyMock.capture](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/Capture.html) feature. However, the examples that I managed to find do not work for me - I get the following compile error at the line with *capture*:

*expect(T) in EasyMock cannot be applied to (void)
reason: no instance of type variable T exist so that void conforms to T*

It would be great if somebody could point out my mistake(s) for me. Below is a code snippet:

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.capture;

import org.easymock.Capture;
import org.easymock.CaptureType;
import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Before;

class B {

}

class A {
    public void doSomething(B input) {

    }
}

public class ATest {
    private Capture<B> capturedData;
    private A testObject;

    @Before
    private void setUp() {
        capturedData = EasyMock.newCapture(CaptureType.ALL);
        testObject = EasyMock.createNiceMock(A.class);
        EasyMock
                .expect(testObject.doSomething(capture(capturedData)))
                .anyTimes();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not related to the capture, but to the return type of your `doSomething()` method:

Since `A.doSomething(B input)` is of return type `void`, you don't expect the method to return anything, thus you cannot use `EasyMock.expect()` for it. Instead, simply invoke the method and use `EasyMock.expectLastCall()`, like so:

```
testObject.doSomething(capture(capturedData));
EasyMock.expectLastCall().anyTimes();
```

`EasyMock.expectLastCall()` declares that you expect the last method invocation before `expectLastCall()` to be executed. You can then handle it just like `expect()`, e.g. add `anyTimes()` to it.